# Entity Framework Core - One to Many without referring source model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am making an application that needs some metadata-handling and some model linking. 
Let's say I have `ModelA` and `ModelB`. I want to have a Entity that stores a list of those two, without them strict knows about that list.

```cs
public class ModelA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class ModelB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class ModelTemplate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<ModelA> ModelAs { get; set; }
    public List<ModelB> ModelBs { get; set; }
}
```

When looking at the migrations it looks like it want to put a reference from `ModelTemplate->Id` into `ModelA` and `ModelB`, but they can be present in mulitple of those lists.

Any tips on where I should look for examples?

Comment: You can't establish a one-to-many relationship without a FK property. If you want, you can have specific DTO's of ModelA and ModelB with the FK properties, and then throw them away in conversion.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro But how will that work when `ModelA` and `ModelB` can be part of multiple `ModelTemplate`'s?

Comment: then you don't need FK properties on ModelA or ModelB, you can use them in a many to many relationship with implicit join table.